Is it possible to have a uniform speed but variable velocity in one-dimension motion?
Is it possible to have a uniform speed but variable velocity in one-dimension motion? I saw a lecture where teacher said that it is possible if particle changes its direction of motion 180$^\circ$.
But a particle should reduce its velocity to turn, right? Or is it possible hypothetically in case of elastic or inelastic collision?

Mathematically you can probably use Green's functions to define instantaneous changes due to impulses, but if you are trying to model it with a Heaviside step function then there is still a discontinuity at the moment of collision. Further, inelastic collisions would change the speed of a single body.

@QPhysl I actually don't know about Green's functions or Heavside step function yet. Can you please provide a simpler explanation.

@QPhysl Do you really mean Green's functions here?
It sounds more like you mean Dirac delta functions instead to model the force.

@ThomasFritsch I mean Green's functions and the Dirac delta distribution models force. If we have $F(t)=-2v_0m\delta(t-t')$ then the EOM is $m\ddot{x}=m\dot{v}=-2v_0m\delta(t-t')$. Since $\frac{d}{dx}H(x)=\delta(x)$ (see this,) the solution to the EOM is $v(t)=v_0-2v_0H(t-t')$, as required. This is an example of a Green's function. Then repeat this where $F(t)$ is periodic and alternating signs and you have the equation describing the motion in the gif in your answer.

Of course this is possible.
Like your teacher said:
Consider a ball bouncing between two walls (like in the animation below).
It has constant speed, and the velocity changes
from positive to negative and back on every bounce.

(animation creted with Animated GIF Maker)

We have make the assumption that the collision is instantaneous right? ( I mean time of collision is neglected)

@NOTEBook Yes, the collisions are assumed to be instantaneous.
